# Passing functions to functions in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin, currying

I am starting to use Vaadin with Kotlin, and have created the following extension method:

```
fun AbstractComponentContainer.addButton(buttonText : String = "", icon : FontIcon? = null, function : (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    val button = Button(buttonText)
    if (icon != null) {
    button.icon = icon
    }
    if (function!=null) {
    button.addClickListener { function() }
    }
    this.addComponent(button)
}
```

This lets me add a button to a container, with an optional click listener (and an optional icon).

I now want to add two buttons to the component, one for up, one for down, to allow me to move items up and down a list. Therefore, I want to call `addButton()` twice. The logic in the lambda is going to be the same, the only difference is that in one the item's position will be incremented and in the other decremented.

I am trying to create a function that can be passed to the `addClickListener`, and to save me writing two functions that do almost the same thing, I want to be able to pass to that function a reference to `Long::plusAssign` and `Long::minusAssign`.

I can't get it to work. Either it won't compile or I get `ClassCastException`s when it runs.

This is where I have got to:

```
val function = { function: (Long) -> Long ->
    val selectedItems: MutableSet<Item> = //get my items
    if (selectedItems.size == 1) {
        val elementAt = selectedItems.elementAt(0)
        elementAt.position = function(elementAt.position)
        Notification("Element's position is now ${elementAt.position}", "", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE, true).show(Page.getCurrent())
        listDataProvider.refreshItem(elementAt)
    }
}
buttonLayout.addButton(buttonText = "Up", function = function(Long::inc) as (()->Unit)?)
buttonLayout.addButton(buttonText = "Down", function = function(Long::dec) as (()->Unit)?)
```

If I remove the cast, it won't compile, and if I leave the cast, I get the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I don't really want to change the signature of the function expected by `addButton`.

(note this is a question about Kotlin, rather than about Vaadin, so I am leaving the Vaadin tag off)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and it is not supported in Kotlin. The workaround is to explicitly create new lambdas:

```
buttonLayout.addButton("Up", function = { function(Long::inc) })
buttonLayout.addButton("Down", function = { function(Long::dec) })
```

Comment: There are actually a few third-party libraries that introduce functional constructs, such as currying into Kotlin: For example Mario Arias' funKTionale (https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale) or memoizr's functional-kotlin-base (https://github.com/memoizr/functional-kotlin-base).

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the solution of Voddan, it seems to be a trick to deal with a problem that we should not have.

The compiler says me that `function` is returning `Unit` instead of `() -> Unit`. It seems logical, so just make a function instead of an `Unit`:

```
val function = fun(longFunction: (Long) -> Long) = {
    val selectedItems: MutableSet<Item> = //get my items
    if (selectedItems.size == 1) {
        val elementAt = selectedItems.elementAt(0)
        elementAt.position = longFunction(elementAt.position)
        Notification("Element's position is now ${elementAt.position}", "", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE, true).show(Page.getCurrent())
        listDataProvider.refreshItem(elementAt)
    }
}
```

So that you can simply do:

```
buttonLayout.addButton("Up", function = function(Long::inc))
buttonLayout.addButton("Down", function = function(Long::dec))
```

In some case and for readability purpose I would sometimes prefer a more explicit/naive solution (is this currying?):

```
val function = fun(longFunction: (Long) -> Long): () -> Unit {
    return fun() {
        val selectedItems: MutableSet<Item> = //get my items
        if (selectedItems.size == 1) {
            val elementAt = selectedItems.elementAt(0)
            elementAt.position = longFunction(elementAt.position)
            Notification("Element's position is now ${elementAt.position}", "", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE, true).show(Page.getCurrent())
            listDataProvider.refreshItem(elementAt)
        }
    }
}
```

On my side it gives the same result, and I find it more natural to read, and easier for developers starting with Kotlin. I don't know if it is a kind of currying or not, but it's compiling and working on my side (tested by mocking the class/event from Vaadin).